# Hibernate Caching and lazy loaded associations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, caching, lazy-initialization

I got a typical entity association of order and items. To make it possible to read only orders, the items set is default FetchType.LAZY. 2nd level and query cache is enabled. To read an order with associated items, I'm using a JPQL query. The query and the entities are cached by EHCache. But on the second call when accessing items, a LazyInitializationException was thrown, because items are not initialized (not restored from cache). Why? What's the best way to implement this requirement?

Order:

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name = Order.NQ_FIND_BY_ID_FETCH_ITEMS, query = "SELECT DISTINCT o FROM Order o JOIN FETCH o.items WHERE o.id = :id")
})
@Table(...)
public class Order extends ... {
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  // @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
  private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>();
  ...
}
```

Item:

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@Table(...)
public class Item extends ... {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
  private Order order;
  ...
}
```

DAO:

```
public class OrderDaoJpaImpl extends ... {

  @Override
  public Catalog findByIdFetchItems(Long id) {
    TypedQuery<Order> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(Order.NQ_FIND_BY_ID_FETCH_ITEMS, Order.class);
    query.setParameter("id", id);
    // query.setHint(QueryHints.HINT_CACHEABLE, Boolean.TRUE);
    Order order = JPAUtil.singleResultOrNull(query);
    return order;
}
```

Service:

```
@Service("orderService")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {

  @Override
  public Order getOrderWithItems(Long orderId) {
    return orderDao.findByIdFetchItems(orderId);
  }
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence ...>
  <persistence-unit name="shop-persistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <jar-file>shop-persistence.jar</jar-file>
    <!-- Enable JPA 2 second level cache -->
    <shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      ...
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Spring Framework 4.3.7.RELEASE and Hibernate 5.2.9.Final.

As you can see, I've tried to use Hibernate entity annotations and cache hints instead of JPA caching. I've also tried JPA entity graphs instead of JOIN FETCH. Always the same: Items are not initialized/restored on the second call of the order query.

Comment: Am I the only one using Hibernate/JPA caching with On-To-Many relations?

Answer (score 3):

The `LazyInitializationException` is thrown because of the [HHH-12430](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12430) issue.

However, there are some issues with your code as well, and there is a workaround that you can use until the Hibernate `HHH-12430` issue is fixed.

When you're using Hibernate, it's not enough to annotate your entity with `@Cacheable`.

You need to provide a [`CacheConcurrencyStrategy`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-store-second-level-cache-entries/) as well:

```
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
```

The Query Cache [only stores entity identifiers](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-query-cache-work/), and since you are only selecting the `Order`, the `items` association will not get cached as well.

What you can do is to change your query to this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = Order.NQ_FIND_BY_ID_FETCH_ITEMS, query = "SELECT DISTINCT o FROM Order o WHERE o.id = :id")
```

Then, activate the cache for collection:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>();
```

And both the `Order` and the `Item` should use this:

```
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = 
    CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
```

since they need to be cacheable.

And make sure you initialize the `items` collection prior to returning the result set:

```
Order order = JPAUtil.singleResultOrNull(query);
if(order != null) {
    order.getItems().size();
}
return order;
```

This way, the `items` will always be initialized and the collection will be fetched from the cache, not from the database.

Comment: Is it possible to use a dto with jpa projection query, instead of order.getItems().size() ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you use a projection query, the result will be cached as-is, but you'll get a tabular DTO representation, not entities. But that's not what the original question wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I think the @Cacheable is not Hibernate cache, but Spring cache.
@Cache annotation is for Hibernate cache.
Besides of this, when I have troubles with this stuff, to get the JOIN FETCH result also usable with cache, I had to add Hibernate.initialize(...) to the Dao method to avoid LazyInitializationException.